# How to clear the previous activity after starting new activity

Tags: android

Hello guys Im having a problem in how to clear the previous activity after starting new activity

I already try this code but it doesn't work when I press back button

here are the code ive tried

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, ErrorActivity.class).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

are they any other ways to do it or something missing from my code ??
I appreciate the for your reply thx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to call `finish()` function.

Comment: I'am sorry I dont understand  when and where to put that code ?

Comment: after `startActivity` function